# Configure Laravel project in Netbeans 8.2

Tags: php, laravel, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 8.2 and I want to use it for Laravel project. I know it is possible to create a Laravel project in Netbeans without going to cmd (*This is what I am trying to achieve*) I have followed these steps to create a Laravel project

1. Install Composer on your system
2. Installer the Composer plugin for Netbeans (It's in the plugins menu, under the PHP category).
3. New Project > PHP Application
4. Go though the wizard, and setup your project. the last step should be named Composer
5. In the last step,search (under Token:) for laravel
6. Select laravel/laravel: The Laravel Framework. and move it to the selected frameworks on the right
7. Click Finish, and you're Done!

Everything went fine! and I am able to create a laravel project from wizard unfortunately as I can see some folders and files (which are always there in Laravel ), I have spend some some hrs searching for a guide on how to integrate Laravel in Netbeans without success. Please help what is wrong with my steps?

[image: Netbeans project structure]

*My Netbeans project structure*